# R - For loop only plots data from one filtered value, despite correctly calculating data frames for each filtered value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate a series of bar charts, one for each of 7 provinces, based off a master data table. However, the software only plots data from one of the provinces -- province 4. When I export to PDF I get 7 of the same bar chart (with different titles).

The data is in this format *(abbreviated for clarity)*

```
province      travelcat pc_pop
60        1   0 to 4 hours 0.6807
21        1   4 to 8 hours 0.1093
28        2   4 to 8 hours 0.0969
44        2 36 to 48 hours 0.0014
31        3 48 to 72 hours 0.0016
49        3     > 72 hours 0.0007
```

Weirdly, when I generate a filtered table `prov_filter` and print that, it shows the data exactly as I'd expect it, specific to each province. Similarly the province title `province_number` is assigned correctly in the resulting PDF printouts. So the filtering is happening...but the data isn't going into the plot.

```
province_list=list()

for (i in unique(slim_prov_TCR$province)) {

  province_number <- paste("Province",i)

  prov_filter <- filter(slim_prov_TCR, province == i)

  print(prov_filter)

  plot <- ggplot(prov_filter, aes(x = prov_filter$travelcat, y = prov_filter$pc_pop)) 
  + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) 
  + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1),labels = scales::percent) 
  + ylab("% of provincial population") + xlab("Travel time to nearest medical facility") 
  + ggtitle(province_number) 
  + stat_summary(fun.y="identity",geom="bar")

  filename=paste(province_number,".pdf",sep="")

  province_list[[i]] = plot
  print(plot)

}
```

I've done this before using similar code with no problems, but this time I've had serial problems, despite revising the filter code using multiple methods. I'm relatively new to R and statistics land in general so I'm probably mucking up something on the grammar side. Any and all help appreciated.

For reference purposes the final printout code is below

```
for (i in unique(slim_prov_TCR$province)) { # Another for loop, this time to save out the bar charts in province_list as PDFs
    province_number <- paste("Province",i)

    filename=paste(province_number,".pdf",sep="") # Make the file name for each PDF. The paste makes the name a variable of the disrict, so each chart is named by sensor

    pdf(filename,width=3.5,height=3.5) # PDF basic specifications. Modify the width and height here.

    print(province_list[[i]])

    dev.off()
}
```

Comment: You should put the `+` at the end of the line of ggplot code, not the beginning, or in some contexts, R will assume the previous line is finished. More likely to be the issue is that you shouldn't use `$` or other subsetting in `aes`; just use the bare variable name. Also, you don't really need a loop; a better option is facetting; see `?facet_wrap`

Comment: alistaire has it - using `$` inside `aes()` instead of just the column names will mess up the plot whenever there are stats, facets, or other fancy plotting features. In this case, your `stat_summary`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice you all. When I remove the `$` I get the following two errors. 1 --  `Error in +scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), labels = scales::percent) : 
  invalid argument to unary operator`. 2 -- 
If I take out scale_y_continuous then I get `Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_setviewport, vp, TRUE) : 
  non-finite location and/or size for viewport` Any thoughts about what these are?

Comment: Aaaand I didn't read that properly. A little more experimentation fixed my problem. Thanks to you all, this works well!

Comment: Maybe you can answer your own question? That way others can learn too? Great job fixing it yourself btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As highlighted by alistaire and Gregor, using `$` for categories and having the `+` at the beginning of lines was confusing R. Reformatting these two points did the trick. See below text.

```
province_list=list()

for (i in unique(slim_prov_TCR$province)) {

  province_number <- paste("Province",i)

  prov_filter <- filter(slim_prov_TCR, province == i)

  print(prov_filter)

  plot <- ggplot(prov_filter, aes(x = travelcat, y = pc_pop)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1),labels = scales::percent) +
    ylab("% of provincial population") + xlab("Travel time to nearest medical facility") +
    ggtitle(province_number) +
    stat_summary(fun.y="identity",geom="bar")

  filename=paste(province_number,".pdf",sep="")

  province_list[[i]] = plot
  print(plot)

}
```